# Detect if requested page is PWA on server side

Tags: plugin-development, wp-redirect, template-redirect

I'm trying to determine if the user is browsing PWA on server side. On client side I can check if the browser mode is `standalone` via JavaScript and detect PWA, but on server side this is not an option. So I'm using simple query parameter for that. Start URL in manifest has query param `isPwa` appended and every time user opens PWA, it goes to `https://example.com/?isPwa`. What I need now is to keep that parameter while user browses PWA, so I need to set `isPwa` parameter to next URL that user opens if the referer URL already had `isPwa` parameter, but my code goes to redirection loop and I'm unable to identify the cause of this. Here's my code:

```
function addIsPwaQueryArg() {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (strpos($referer, 'isPwa') !== false) {
        $location = remove_query_arg('isPwa');
        wp_redirect(add_query_arg('isPwa', '', $location));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'addIsPwaQueryArg');
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and why is it not working?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the referrer, it can be modified by the user, spoofed, and lots of browsers and extensions strip it for privacy purposes

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the actual querystring to [`remove_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_query_arg/). After some quick testing, I think your `$location` value is probably an empty string, and the location you're attempting to redirect to is `?isPwa`.

The 2nd parameter to `remove_query_arg()` should be the `$referer` value.

```
function addIsPwaQueryArg() {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (strpos($referer, 'isPwa') !== false) {
        $location = remove_query_arg('isPwa', $referer );
        wp_redirect(add_query_arg('isPwa', '', $location));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'addIsPwaQueryArg');
```

**However:** I'm not sure that's the root cause of your redirect loop. It looks like you're checking to see if `isPwa` is in the querystring, removing it if it is, and then adding it back in (with a blanked value) as you redirect. Is this your intent?

Comment: Redirection is happening on the correct URL as I see in the browser address bar, so If I'm on `https://example.com/?isPwa` and click the link, it redirects on `https://example.com/link/?isPwa` but browser displaying `redirected too many times` error.

That's what I'm trying to achieve: Checking to see if `isPwa` was in previous URL querystring and then adding it back (with a blanked value) if it was in next URL.

Comment: Check your webserver logs to see what redirection is actually happening. You should see a bunch of `301` or `302` statuses pop up in there when you load the page; that might give you some insight as to why you're getting `redirected too many times`. (It's possible you'll need to ask your web hosting provider for assistance.)

Comment: I think after the redirection, the logic see new referer with `?isPwa` param and redirects it again, resulting in the redirection loop.